# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'?

Tags: angular

Parameter 'post' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

```
storedPosts=[];
  OnPostAdded(post){
    this.storedPosts.push(post);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen the tutorial you are following, the fix was posted early in the first lecture when installing nodeJs.

You'll need to go into the tsconfig.json file of your project and set "strict" to false, then save, close the ng server and re-compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding types..

```
storedPosts: any[] = [];
  OnPostAdded(post: any){
    this.storedPosts.push(post);
  }
```

As you are using typescript; you should consider providing types for your data instead of any. You can create an interface to describe the data; this will also make the code readable for other developers

Comment: Getting this error after replacing to your solution =Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'

Comment: what is the type of post parameter?

Comment: post parameter type is any

Comment: no i mean the actual value.. for example what does it hold? a string, a number?

Comment: It Holds Array.

Comment: so u need to have an array of arrays?

Comment: @Petros It solved my error (which, I had ), but when the instructor did this, without using types, his code worked! Although he was using a lower Angular Version. Can you tell me if the latest Angular has this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration in tsconfig.json
disable "strict" : true;
and enable "noImplicitAny": false

Answer (score 0):

It might be redundant to say it, but in my case I was trying to use the `emit()` method to push out a `prop: MyObject[]`.

At first I ""resolved"" the issue by changing my MyObject properties by defining them as [optional `?:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116960/12761167), but later on we realized the fault was that in my `EventEmitter` initialization I forgot to add `[]` after `MyObject`

***BEFORE***

```
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter<MyObject>();
```

**AFTER**

```
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter<MyObject[]>();
```